# Vulkan: Can't find info on a particular usecase, regarding preserve attachments, in the Spec

Tags: vulkan

Imagine a usecase where an attachment is included in the first subpass of a RenderPass as a preserve attachment. I'll defined the "first subpass" as subpass A, where there is a RenderPass with N subpasses, and there are dependencies between its subpasses where A must be executed first.

Now, that usecase doesn't make sense to me. However, I went to look for clarity about that in the Spec and, so far, I haven't come across anything forbidding it. In my code, I'm handling this now by issuing an assertion failure when I detected that. But, I would really like to hear from the Spec's mouth that this is, in fact, not a legal/sensical thing to do. I'm trying to avoid making assumptions.

If someone knows where I could find reliable info regarding this usecase, please point me to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preserve attachments exist to deal with the following scenario:

You have a subpass A which manipulates an attachment. You have a subpass C which uses the data generated into that attachment by A. Therefore, there is some dependency between A and C. However, you *also* have a subpass B which depends on some other data generated by A, *and* which C depends on as well (thus, A and C's dependency can be implicit based on the A->B and B->C dependencies).

That is, subpass B *must* execute between A and C. But let's also say that subpass B *itself* doesn't use the particular attachment that A generated for C.

Because the execution graph requires that B execute between A and C, any hardware that implements this execution graph may need to allocate some storage within subpass B to make sure that this attachment's contents are preserved. On tile based renderers in particular, such storage is often at a premium. Therefore, the Vulkan API *requires* that you explicitly state in subpass B's definition that the attachment from A needs to be preserved while B is executing, even though B doesn't use it for anything.

This is the *only place* where preserving an attachment matters. Even so, there is nothing in the Vulkan specification that *forbids* the use of a preserve attachment outside of this scenario. You will find no statement in the specification that says that this is forbidden, only a statement about where preserve attachments are *necessary*.

Now, this *doesn't* mean you should just shove preserve attachments anywhere. You should use them when they are required, but that's it.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer. I do have an understanding of their use. My particular reason for looking for a specific answer from the Spec is that I'm building a RenderGraph compiler kind of thing, and I would like to support all the operations that are possible to do as part of defining and using RenderPasses. If it's not illegal, perhaps the functionality could be used in some obscure way to achive some obscure goal for which I don't have a faint idea that it's possible. It's more of a robustness thing.

Comment: The Spec has plenty of places where they specifically forbid things, and I was hoping that it would be more clear about the legality of this usecase. In the grand scheme of things, it's not a huge deal; it would just be ideal to have a definitive answer, if possible. Because of the work i'm currently doing, i've had time to think somewhat deep about minute details of renderpasses. The compiler should be able to handle whatever legal work is thrown at it, and as small as some details could be, they need to be handled *somehow*.

Comment: If A uses the attachment as output, and C uses the attachment as input, couldn't the driver assume that it needs to be preserved? I can't think of any use case were you are writing to an attachment in subpass A, and later you would like to read undefined data from that attachment in subpass C.

Comment: @tuket: By all rights, you could say the same thing about subpass dependencies. The driver could see that subpass C uses an attachment used by A and therefore there must exist an execution dependency between them. But it doesn't; you must *explicitly* spell out such relationships. This is just another case of having to explicitly spell things out.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok. At least subpass dependencies provide some info in the form of accessMask and stageMask. In the case of `pPreserveAttachments`, I think it doesn't provide any additional info to `VkRenderPassCreateInfo`. Anyways, I guess it's just the nature of the API .Thanks for your reply